# Visual Studio Team Services Compile was Successful but no EXE files

Tags: c++, visual-studio, azure-devops

Ok, so i tried to compile my application using VS Team Services and i didn't get any errors, but i didn't get any .exe files, also what should i do?

Thank you in advance!

```html
******************************************************************************
Initializing Hosted Agent
******************************************************************************
Requesting an Agent from the Hosted Agent Pool
Hosted Agent successfully assigned.
Configuring connection settings for Hosted Agent
Starting Hosted Agent
Initializing connection to Hosted Agent
Successfully connected to Hosted Agent
******************************************************************************
Starting: Build
******************************************************************************
Executing the following commandline:
C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\default\agent\worker\vsoWorker.exe  /name:Worker-8f36227c-7965-4c0e-b7de-f55a30e3e667 /id:8f36227c-7965-4c0e-b7de-f55a30e3e667 /rootFolder:"C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\default" /logger:Forwarding,1.0.0;Verbosity=Verbose,Name=Agent1-1aadeebb9c4390e852d65e80b5fec753;JobId=8f36227c-7965-4c0e-b7de-f55a30e3e667
******************************************************************************
Starting: Get sources
******************************************************************************
Syncing repository: keylogger (TFVC)
Workspace Name: ws_1_1;Build\fc5ab742-a527-4aad-b4d1-2179517859b8
Getting C:\a\1\s;C22
Getting C:\a\1\s\bzip2;C25
Getting C:\a\1\s\kl_http.sln;C37
Getting C:\a\1\s\bzip2\AzureContinuousDeployment.11.xaml;C25
Getting C:\a\1\s\bzip2\bzip2.vcproj;C31
Getting C:\a\1\s\bzip2\bzip2.vcxproj;C29
Getting C:\a\1\s\bzip2\bzip2.vcxproj.filters;C30
Getting C:\a\1\s\bzip2\bzip2.vcxproj.user;C26
Getting C:\a\1\s\bzip2\code.c;C26
Getting C:\a\1\s\bzip2\DefaultTemplate.11.1.xaml;C34
Getting C:\a\1\s\bzip2\functions.c;C26
Getting C:\a\1\s\bzip2\globals.h;C32
Getting C:\a\1\s\bzip2\LabDefaultTemplate.11.xaml;C25
Getting C:\a\1\s\bzip2\logger.c;C26
Getting C:\a\1\s\bzip2\UpgradeTemplate.xaml;C25
Getting C:\a\1\s\bzip2\zip.cpp;C28
Getting C:\a\1\s\bzip2\zip.h;C28
Done syncing repository keylogger to version C37 (workspace version C37)
******************************************************************************
Running tasks
******************************************************************************
******************************************************************************
Starting task: Build solution $/keylogger/kl_http.sln
******************************************************************************
Executing the powershell script: C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\default\tasks\VSBuild\1.0.16\VSBuild.ps1
C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\default\agent\worker\tools\NuGet.exe restore "C:\a\1\s\kl_http.sln" -NonInteractive
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin'.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe "C:\a\1\s\kl_http.sln" /nologo /m /nr:false /fl /flp:"logfile=C:\a\1\s\kl_http.sln.log" /dl:CentralLogger,"C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\default\agent\worker\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll"*ForwardingLogger,"C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\default\agent\worker\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll"  /p:platform="win32" /p:configuration="release" /p:VisualStudioVersion="14.0"
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
Build started 12/24/2015 5:23:31 PM.
Project "C:\a\1\s\kl_http.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
  Building solution configuration "release|win32".
The target "BeforeGenerateProjectPriFile" listed in a BeforeTargets attribute at "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\NuGet\Microsoft.NuGet.targets (186,61)" does not exist in the project, and will be ignored.
Project "C:\a\1\s\kl_http.sln" (1) is building "C:\a\1\s\bzip2\bzip2.vcxproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "Release\".
  Creating directory "C:\a\1\s\Release\".
InitializeBuildStatus:
  Creating "Release\kl_http.unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
ClCompile:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\CL.exe /c /Zi /nologo /W3 /WX- /O1 /Oi /Os /Oy- /GL /D WIN32 /D NDEBUG /D _CONSOLE /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /MD /GS /Gy /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Fo"Release\\" /Fd"Release\vc100.pdb" /Gd /TP /analyze- /errorReport:queue code.c functions.c logger.c zip.cpp
  code.c
  functions.c
  logger.c
  zip.cpp
Link:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE /OUT:"C:\a\1\s\Release\kl_http.exe" /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib /MANIFEST /ManifestFile:"Release\kl_http.exe.intermediate.manifest" /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /PDB:"C:\a\1\s\Release\kl_http.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF /LTCG /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:"C:\a\1\s\Release\kl_http.lib" /MACHINE:X86 Release\code.obj
  Release\functions.obj
  Release\logger.obj
  Release\zip.obj
     Creating library C:\a\1\s\Release\kl_http.lib and object C:\a\1\s\Release\kl_http.exp
  Generating code
  Finished generating code
  bzip2.vcxproj -> C:\a\1\s\Release\kl_http.exe
Manifest:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\mt.exe /nologo /verbose /outputresource:"C:\a\1\s\Release\kl_http.exe;#1" /manifest Release\kl_http.exe.intermediate.manifest
FinalizeBuildStatus:
  Deleting file "Release\kl_http.unsuccessfulbuild".
  Touching "Release\kl_http.lastbuildstate".
Done Building Project "C:\a\1\s\bzip2\bzip2.vcxproj" (default targets).
Done Building Project "C:\a\1\s\kl_http.sln" (default targets).
Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)
Time Elapsed 00:00:31.58
******************************************************************************
Finishing task: VSBuild
******************************************************************************
******************************************************************************
Starting task: Test Assemblies **\$(BuildConfiguration)\*test*.dll;-:**\obj\**
******************************************************************************
Executing the powershell script: C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\default\tasks\VSTest\1.0.24\VSTest.ps1
No test assemblies found matching the pattern: **\release\*test*.dll;-:**\obj\**
******************************************************************************
Finishing task: VSTest
******************************************************************************
******************************************************************************
Starting task: Publish symbols path:
******************************************************************************
Executing the powershell script: C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\default\tasks\PublishSymbols\1.0.12\PublishSymbols.ps1
Find-Files -SearchPattern **\bin\**\*.pdb -RootFolder C:\a\1\s
Found 0 symbol files to index.
No files were selected for indexing.
******************************************************************************
Finishing task: PublishSymbols
******************************************************************************
******************************************************************************
Starting task: Copy Publish Artifact: drop
******************************************************************************
Executing the powershell script: C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\default\tasks\CopyPublishBuildArtifacts\1.0.13\CopyPublishBuildArtifacts.ps1
Preparing artifact content in staging folder C:\a\1\a...
Total files copied: 0.
Max Concurrent Uploads 1, Max Creators 1
Found 0 files to upload.
Created 0 files without uploading content. Total files processed 0
Uploaded artifact 'C:\a\1\a\drop' to container folder 'drop' of build 10.
Associated artifact 8 with build 10
******************************************************************************
Finishing task: CopyPublishBuildArtifacts
******************************************************************************
******************************************************************************
Finishing Build
******************************************************************************
Worker Worker-8f36227c-7965-4c0e-b7de-f55a30e3e667 finished running job 8f36227c-7965-4c0e-b7de-f55a30e3e667
```

I tried compiling this many times and trying a lot of times.

Comment: where did you searched for the .exe?

Comment: everywhere in the code folders

Comment: and they weren't created, read the log

Comment: are you doing this via debug or release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the logs you provided, the exe is created successfully during the build. See following:

> Generating code
>   Finished generating code
>   bzip2.vcxproj ->
>   C:\a\1\s\Release\kl_http.exe

The issue is in your build definition, the "Copy and Publish Build Artifacts" step. By default, it is copying the files under "**\bin" folder to "drop" artifact folder. However this is not applicable for C++ project. In your case, you are running a build with "release" configuration, so the compiled files are generated in "Release" folder (Like this: C:\a\1\s\Release\kl_http.exe). So you need to change "**\bin" to "**\release" for "Copy and Publish Build Artifacts" step in your build definition. This change is also applicable for "Index Sources & Publish Symbols" step.

Comment: i am getting an error "Indexed source information could not be retrieved from C:\a\1\s\Release\kl_http.exe. Error: Symbol is not of type pdb.
" but i know how to fix it

Comment: I added a batch script that renames C:\a\1\s\Release\kl_http.exe to kl_http.pdb